# Combining nested query get illegal_state_exception failed to find nested object under path

Tags: elasticsearch, nested

I'm creating a query on Elasticsearch, for find documents through all indices.
I need to combine should, must and nested query on Elasticsearch, i get the right result but i get an error inside the result.

This is the query I'm using

```
GET _all/_search
{
  "query": {
      "bool": {
        "minimum_should_match": 1,
        "should": [
          { "term": { "trimmed_final_url": "https://www.repubblica.it/t.../" } }
        ],
        "must": [
          {
            "nested": {
              "path": "entities",
              "query": {
                "bool": {
                  "must": [
                    { "term": { "entities.id": "138511" } }
                  ]
                }
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "term": {
              "language": { "value": "it" }
             }
          }
        ]
      }
  }
```

And this is the result

```
{
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 38,
    "successful" : 14,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 24,
    "failures" : [
      {
        "shard" : 0,
        "index" : ".kibana_1",
        "node" : "7twsq85TSK60LkY0UiuWzA",
        "reason" : {
          "type" : "query_shard_exception",
          "reason" : """
            failed to create query: {
            ...
              "index_uuid" : "HoHi97QFSaSCp09iSKY1DQ",
              "index" : ".reporting-2019.06.02",
              "caused_by" : {
                "type" : "illegal_state_exception",
                "reason" : "[nested] failed to find nested object under path [entities]"
              }
            }
          },
            ...
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 50,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : 16.90015,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "i_201906_v1",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "MugcbmsBAzi8a0oJt96Q",
        "_score" : 16.90015,
        "_source" : {
          "language" : "it",
          "entities" : [
            {
              "id" : 101580,
            },
            {
              "id" : 156822,
            },
            ...
```

I didn't write some fields because the code is too long

Answer (score 5):

I am new to StackOverFlow (made this account to answer this question :D) so if this answer is out of line bear with me. I have been dabbling in nested fields in Elasticsearch recently so I have some ideas as to how this error could be appearing.
Have you defined a mapping for your document type? I don't believe Elasticsearch will recognize the field as nested if you do not tell it to do so in the mapping:

```
PUT INDEX_NAME
{
  "mappings": {
      "DOC_TYPE": {
          "properties": {
              "entities": {"type": "nested"}
          }
      }
   }
}
```

You may have to specify this mapping for each index and document type. Not sure if there is a way to do that all with one request.

I also noticed you have a "should" clause with minimum matches set to 1. I believe this is exactly the same as a "must" clause so I am not sure what purpose this achieves (correct me if I'm wrong). If your mapping is specified, the query should look something like this:

```
GET /_all/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "entities",
            "query": {
              "term": {
                "entities.id": {
                  "value": "138511"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "language": {
              "value": "it"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "trimmed_final_url": {
              "value": "https://www.repubblica.it/t.../"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answer, I have a "should" clause with minimum matches set to 1, because i would test the speed. The mapping exist. I think there are some document doesn't match the mapping or there are some other index with document that have different mapping. When i'll found the issue i will answer. Sorry for my English and thank you again!